# Getting GPG error while running "sudo apt-get update" command

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, gnupg

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit).

```
$ sudo apt-get update   
.
.
.
Fetched 2,079 kB in 1min 1s (33.7 kB/s)                                        
Reading package lists... Done  
W: GPG error: http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com HDP InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B9733A7A07513CAD  
W: GPG error: http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com HDP-UTILS InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B9733A7A07513CAD
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Import keys from MIT keyserver:

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys B9733A7A07513CAD
gpg -a --export 07513CAD | apt-key add -
```