# apt-get update get GPG error running Ubuntu 14.04 in VMWare

Tags: apt, vmware

I am currently on Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware Workstation12. I tried install cmake 3.6.2 at first, while I get the error

```
Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Then I searched it on the Internet, get this answer http://www.cnblogs.com/suyuan1573/p/4251389.html, when run  `sudo apt-get upgrade`, get

```
E: GPG error: http://ubuntu.cn99.com precise InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I looked into multiple solution on the Internet including these

- [How to fix GPG error/BADSIG while running apt-get update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17606/how-to-fix-gpg-error-badsig-while-running-apt-get-update)
- [getting GPG error while runnign "sudo apt-get update" command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633345/getting-gpg-error-while-runnign-sudo-apt-get-update-command), and
- [How to fix GPG error/BADSIG while running apt-get update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17606/how-to-fix-gpg-error-badsig-while-running-apt-get-update).

All doesn't work for me.

How to solve the problem? Thanks, allanna.

I don't wanna re-install Ubuntu, now I can't install any software. When I type 
 apt-get update, I get  E: GPG error: http://ubuntu.cn99.com precise InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

Comment: The last command was failing for predictably, because Ubuntu 10.10 is end-of-life long ago.

Comment: Thank u, but how to fix "Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)", I've spent about one day to install cmake. I'm almost corrupted. Thank u for your help , I'm new to ubuntu too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about proxy problem. I altered the proxy links.
Firstly backup the proxy list:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list_backup
```

Then open sources.list with gedit or other editor:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Choose the approxiate list for u, I'm in China, this works well:

```
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
```

ps: delete the original list

Finally, run

```
sudo apt-get upadate
```

Comment: It's same as I suggested in my answer to change the mirror